# Sequences that don't count algebraic structures on finite sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, universal-algebra

People count [$n$-element groups](https://oeis.org/A000001), [$n$-element monoids](https://oeis.org/A058129), [$n$-element commutative monoids](https://oeis.org/A001426), etcetera - always up to isomorphism.  The algebraic structures I've listed, and many more, are studied systematically in [universal algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_algebra).  In this subject any [theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variety_(universal_algebra)#Definition)
$T$ with a finite signature - loosely, any finite collection of finitary operations obeying equational laws - will give a sequence $(T_n)_{n \ge 0}$ where $T_n$ is the number of isomorphism classes of algebras of $T$ having $n$ elements.  [Andrej Bauer](https://mathstodon.xyz/@andrejbauer/111022844324484350) dubbed $T_n$ the **model sequence** of the theory $T$.

For example, if $T$ is the theory of groups we have

$$ T_0 = 0, \; T_1 = 1, \; T_2 = 1, \; T_3 = 1, \; T_4 = 2, $$
$$ T_5 = 1, \; T_6 = 2, \; T_7 = 1, \; T_8 = 5, \dots$$

My (revised) question is: what are all the constraints on sequences $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ of natural numbers that are model sequences?

There may be easy constraints on model sequences that I haven't noticed.  The two I noticed are:

- we must have $T_0 = 0$ or $T_0 = 1$.
- the number of $k$-ary operations on an $n$-element set is $n^{n^k}$, which leads to an upper bound on the growth rate of $T_n$, given that there are only finitely many operations.

Comment: You also have $T_1=1$, don't you?

Comment: A constraint: if $T_n,T_m\neq 0$ then $T_{nm}\neq 0$.

Comment: Even more so, $T_{nm} \leq (nm)! T_n T_m$ since $T_n$ is the lower bound for the number of algebras having $n$ elements not up to isomorphism, that sequence is supermultiplicative, and $T_n n!$ is an upper bound for the number of algebras having $n$ elements not up to isomorphism. This bound can surely be improved: I think $T_2 (T_2+1) /2 \leq 3 T_4$ since each four-element algebra can be written as a product of two two-element algebras (without ordering them) in at most 3 ways.

Comment: @WillSawin you rather conclude $T_{nm}\ge T_nT_m/(nm)!$, don't you?

Comment: @JosephVanName I don’t see why that should be the case. First, there is no known polynomial-time algorithm to compute a canonical form up to isomorphism, hence even for nice classes, it’s only something like #PH. Second, if the algebraic theory is not finitely axiomatizable, it may not be recognizable in P whether a given algebra is a model of $T$; in fact, I don’t even see why it should be computable at all.

Comment: Actually, the latter is a problem already in the OP: even in a finite signature, there are infinitely many equations, $2^\omega$ possible theories, and likely $2^\omega$ different model sequences. So it’s *not* a priori clear that “there are many such sequences that are not model sequences”.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek You are right. I was thinking about finitely axiomatizable theories because Baez mentioned that there are only countably many classes, and I forgot about isomorphism. Maybe we need to add a new complexity class $\#P/\simeq$.

Comment: Why is T0 for groups equal to 1. I believe the empty set is not a group because a group has a zero-ary operation the identity

Comment: Groups should have $T_0 = 0$, but the listed sequence is correct for the theory of associative quasigroups.

Comment: I've always been impressed that while there are 5 isomorphism classes of groups of order 8, there are 3,684,030,417 isomorphism classes of semigroups of order 8. Seems quite extraordinary to me. (Sloane A027851)

Comment: I was sure I typed $T_0 = 0$.

Comment: @DaveBenson Most of these are 3-step nilpotent, ie the product of any three elements is 0. This automatically guarantees associativity, and is quite easy to guarantee in a binary relation. This explains the vast amount of semigroups (but most of them are quite boring).

Comment: The usual term for a "model sequence" is the *fine spectrum* of a universal algebraic variety; the *spectrum* being the set of indices on which the fine spectrum is non-zero (e.g. Boolean algebras have spectrum $\{2^n\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, and the fine spectrum takes the value 1 on any of these indices). You can put immediate constraints on fine spectra using the fact that algebraic structures are closed under products, but in 1979 [Taylor](https://www.math.uh.edu/~hjm/hjmathsurvey_1979.pdf) wrote that *characterization of such functions seems hopeless*: it appears this hasn't changed yet.

Comment: @Z.A.K.: Many thanks for letting me know wha this is. On Mastodon I was asking for references.

Comment: is the sequence $T_n = n!$ possible?

Comment: @TimCampion Isn't that the sequence for the theory of two unary operations f and g satisfying the identities f(g(x)) = g(f(x)) = x?

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena No, because the structures are counted up to isomorphism. The number of permutations up to isomorphism is not $n!$, but the partition number.

Comment: $(\aleph_1,\aleph_2,\aleph_3,\dots)$

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Right! Thanks for correcting me!

Answer (score 9):

The original question was:

**My question is: can anyone name a sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$
of natural numbers that grows more slowly than exponentially,
yet is not a model sequence?**

Any model sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ must satisfy
$$
a_n\leq a_{n^k}
$$
for all $n, k\geq 1$.
This follows from Theorem 4.2 of

Operations with structures
László Lovász
Acta Mathematica Academiae Scientiarum Hungarica
volume 18, (1967) 321-328

which states:

**(4.2)** If $A$ and $B$ are finite structures and $A^n\cong B^n$,
then $A\cong B$.

One applies Lovasz's Theorem as follows to prove the inequality
$a_n\leq a_{n^k}$.
Assume that $A_1, \ldots, A_{a_n}$ is a list
of algebras in the variety which represents all
isomorphism types of $n$-element algebras. Then
$A_1^k, \ldots, A_{a_n}^k$ is a list of $n^k$-element
algebras which represent distinct
isomorphism types of $n^k$-element algebra.
This shows that $a_n\leq a_{n^k}$.

One can use this to exhibit an explicit sub-exponential
sequence that is not a model sequence,
such as the almost-constant
sequence $(a_{n})_{n\geq 1}$ where $a_n = 17$
for all $n$ except that $a_{25}=3$. (For then, $a_5\not\leq a_{5^2}$.)

---

A paper relevant to this question is

The fine spectrum of a variety
Walter Taylor
Algebra Univ. 5 (1975) 263-303

Taylor introduces the *fine spectrum*
of a variety $\mathcal V$ as follows:
$$
f_{\mathcal V}(\lambda) = \textrm{the number of isomorphism
types of $\mathcal V$-algebras of size $\lambda$.}
$$
Taylor was interested in those varieties
with finitely many isomorphism types of algebras
of size $n$ for any $n\in\omega$. (Let me call these
finite-ish varieties. Any variety defined with finitely
many basic operations is finite-ish.)
If $\mathcal V$ is finite-ish, then $f_{\mathcal V}\in \omega^{\omega}$
(the [Baire space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_space_(set_theory))).
Taylor asks:
Let $F\subseteq \omega^{\omega}$ be the set of fine
spectra of finite-ish varieties.
Is $F$ closed in $\omega^{\omega}$?

This question is still open. In the 1980's,
both Ralph McKenzie and I proved independently
that
the topological closure of $F$ in $\omega^{\omega}$
is the set $P$ = the set of fine spectra of all
finite-ish pseudovarieties. (A pseudovariety is a class of finite
algebras closed under the formation of homomorphic
images,
subalgebras, and finite products.)
What remains to determine is whether $F=P$.

Comment: Sorry, that was a stray moment. On Mastodon I was pointed to https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/288120858.pdf as a source of previous work.

Answer (score 1):

Because it's too long for a comment I'll post this as an answer: I just want to provide [Omar Antolín](https://mathstodon.xyz/@oantolin/111029829014305557)'s nice proofs of the following facts.  These facts probably go  back to this paper:

- László Lovász, [Operations with structures](https://www.cs.elte.hu/%7Elovasz/scans/opstruct.pdf), *Acta Mathematica Academiae Scientiarum Hungarica* **18**, (1967) 321–328.

but Lovász did not phrase them using category theory.

**Theorem 1.**  Suppose $T$ is a [Lawvere theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere+theory) having finitely many isomorphism classes of algebras of cardinality $n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$.  If $(a_n)_{n \ge 0}$ is the number of isomorphism classes of algebras of cardinality $n$, then

$$    a_{n^k} \ge a_n $$

for each $n, k \in \mathbb{N}$.

This follows easily from

**Theorem 2.** Let $A, B$ be two algebras of a Lawvere theory whose underlying sets are finite.  If $A^k \cong B^k$ for some natural number $k$ then $A \cong B$.

Theorem 2 in turn follows from this lemma:

**Super-Yoneda Lemma.** Let $\mathsf{C}$ be the category of algebras of some Lawvere theory, and let $A, B \in \mathsf{C}$ be two algebras whose underlying sets are finite.  If the functors $\mathrm{hom}(-,A)$ and $\mathrm{hom}(-,A)$ are unnaturally isomorphic, then $A \cong B$.

Here we say the functors $\mathrm{hom}(-,A)$ and $\mathrm{hom}(-,B)$ are **unnaturally isomorphic** if

$$  \mathrm{hom}(X,A) \cong \mathrm{hom}(X,B) $$

for all $X \in \mathsf{C}$.  We're not imposing the usual naturality condition involving a commuting square — indeed we can't, since we're not even giving any specific choice of isomorphism!

If $A$ and $B$ are objects in any category and $\mathrm{hom}(-,A)$ and $\mathrm{hom}(-,B)$ naturally isomorphic, we can show $A \cong B$ using the Yoneda Lemma.  But when they're unnaturally isomorphic, we need to use the Super-Yoneda Lemma, which has more restrictive hypotheses.

Here's how the Super-Yoneda Lemma implies Theorem 2..  Since $A^k \cong B^k$, we have natural isomorphisms

$$ \mathrm{hom}(-,A)^k \cong \mathrm{hom}(-, A^k) \cong \mathrm{hom}(-, B^k) \cong \mathrm{hom}(-,B)^k $$

so for any $X \in \mathsf{C}$ the sets $\mathrm{hom}(X,A)^k$ and $\mathrm{hom}(X,B)^k$ have the same cardinality.  This means we have an *unnatural* isomorphism

$$  \mathrm{hom}(-,A) \cong \mathrm{hom}(-,B) $$

The lemma then lets us conclude that

$$ A \cong B $$

Next let's turn to the lemma. I'll just quote Omar Antolín's proof, since I can't improve on it.   Remember, $A$ and $B$ are algebras of some Lawvere theory whose underlying sets are finite:

> Let $\mathrm{mon}(X, A)$ be the set of monomorphisms, which here are just homomorphisms that are injective functions. I claim you can compute the cardinality of $\mathrm{mon}(X, A)$ using the inclusion-exclusion principle in terms of the cardinalities of $\mathrm{hom}(Q, A)$ for various quotients of $X$.

> Indeed, for any pair of elements $x, y \in X$, let $S(x, y)$ be the set for homomorphisms $f \colon X \to A$ such that $f(x) = f(y)$. The monomorphisms are just the homomorphisms that belong to none of the sets $S(x, y)$, so you can compute how many there are via the inclusion-exclusion formula: you'll just need the cardinality of intersections of several $S(x_i, y_i)$.

> Now, the intersection of some $S(x_i, y_i)$ is the set of homorphisms $f$ such that for all $i$, $f(x_i) = f(y_i)$. Those are in bijection with the homorphisms $Q \to A$ where $Q$ is the quotient of $X$ obtained by adding the relations $x_i=y_i$ for each $i$.

> So far I hope I've convinced you that if $\mathrm{hom}(-, A)$ and $\mathrm{hom}(-, B)$ are *unnaturally* isomorphic, so are $\mathrm{mon}(-, A)$ and $\mathrm{mon}(-, B)$. Now it's easy to finish: since $\mathrm{mon}(A, A)$ is non-empty, so is $\mathrm{mon}(A, B)$, so $A$ is isomorphic to a subobject of $B$. Similarly $B$ is isomorphic to a subobject of $A$, and since they are finite, they must be isomorphic.

If you examine this argument you'll see we didn't use the full force of the assumptions.  We didn't need $A$ and $B$ to be algebras of a Lawvere theory. They could have been topological spaces, or posets, or simple graphs, or various other things.  It seems all we really need is a category $\mathsf{C}$ of gadgets with a forgetful functor

$$  U \colon \mathsf{C} \to \mathsf{FinSet} $$

that is faithful and has some extra property... *roughly*, that we can take an object in $\mathsf{C}$ and take a quotient of it where we impose a bunch of extra relations $x_i = y_i$, and maps out of this quotient will behave as you'd expect.   More precisely, I think the extra property is this:

> Given any $X \in \mathsf{C}$ and any surjection $p \colon U(X) \to S$, there is a morphism $j \colon X \to Q$ such that the morphisms $f \colon X \to A$ that factor through $j$ are precisely those for which $U(f)$ factors through $p$.

I would like to understand this better.   This paper should help:

- Luca Reggio, [Polyadic sets and homomorphism counting](https://arxiv.org/abs/2110.11061).

but I haven't had time to absorb it yet.   Here's the abstract:

> A classical result due to Lovasz (1967) shows that the isomorphism type of a graph is determined by homomorphism counts. That is, graphs $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic whenever the number of homomorphisms from $K$ to $G$ is the same as the number of homomorphisms from $K$ to $H$ for all graphs $K$. Variants of this result, for various classes of finite structures, have been exploited in a wide range of research fields, including graph theory and finite model theory.

> We provide a categorical approach to homomorphism counting based on the concept of polyadic (finite) set. The latter is a special case of the notion of polyadic space introduced by Joyal (1971) and related, via duality, to Boolean hyperdoctrines in categorical logic. We also obtain new homomorphism counting results applicable to a number of infinite structures, such as finitely branching trees and profinite algebras.

Comment: Typo in Theorem 1? $a_{n^k}\ge a_n$ rather than $\le$. This was the main contents of [Keith Kearnes' answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/454209/14094), by the way.